# d3 (multi-series) line graph being filled in

Tags: d3.js, graph, line

[image: Graph being filled in.]

Has anyone ever seen this behaviour and knows how to fix it?

Each line that I render comes 'filled in' with a strange dark shadow.
I don't want this behaviour. I don't even know what to call this behaviour, I'm sure it's probably got a name.

I made my y values random and got this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ahhh..silly me.

on the path element, be sure to add

.attr('fill', 'none')